# Cucumber Selenium Java-Running Scenarios Outline with multiple examples

Tags: selenium, cucumber, scenarios

Can anyone help me to find solution for the below use case:

Currently I am working on Selenium Automation using Cucumber and I have the below Issue.

I need to automate scenario in web application.

```
Scenario Outline
Login as "<User>" and purchase items and checkout by selecting "<Option>".
Examples:
|User|
|Arun|
|Ajay|
|Ashok|
Examples
|Option|  
|one|
|two|
|Three|
```

Here the I need to see 9 times running the same scenario  till (option 3) for each user.

I mean When Arun login he should checkout and select option one (EG: he place an order without description entered) and then again Arun should login and should checkout and select option two (this time he enters the description and place an order) and then again arun login as select option 3 (EG: Enters description and selects some checkbox and place an order).

This need to repeated for Ajay and Ashok as well. How do I achieve this in Cucumber. Can I use Multiple Examples for single Scenario Outline.

Or Is it possible to have Examples in Background.

This is one of the important use case I need to automate and been trying out with various options in Cucumber. But nothing works.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can write the scenario outline as given below. it may be useful.

```
Scenario Outline: Login as <user> and Purchase item with the option <option>
When I login as <user>
And I enter the description <description> 
And I checkout the item using the option <option>

Examples:
|user|description|option|
|Arun |Some Desc|One  |
|Arun |         |One  |
|Arun |Some Desc|two  |
|Ajay |         |three|
|Ajay |Some Desc|two  |
|Ajay |Some Desc|three|
|Ashok|         |One  |
|Ashok|Some Desc|two  |
|Ashok|Some Desc|three|
```

This will run all the steps with different user, description and options.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I have tried this before and it works fine.But Here I have more use cases to automate for each user login,

Comment: For EG: Scenario Ou tline

Comment: For EG: I need to automate an scenario  When Arun login He need to checkout with option one and pick items from Top chart.and then place an order.Then again Arun Login and select option 1 and pick item from search text field and place an order.Like that I have 4 ways to pick items.So Let me give  better clarity here Each user will have 16 use cases ..Is there any way i Can do this using Examples Or Background.

Comment: |User    Checkoutoption   Item selection
Arun           zero            zero
               one             one 
               two             two 


Ajay           zero  zero 
  one  one       
 In this Arun login and selects Checkout option zero and with checkout option zero he needs to selectfor all three options under Items selection and more important he should  placing each order for item selection

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to add too many use cases in a single scenario outline. Why not create multiple? Better readability for everyone involved.

Comment: As Daniel said, you could have split the use cases into multiple scenario outline for each scenario instead of have all in a scenario outline.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Login with purchase and checkout
  Given I am on the login page
  When I log in as "<User>"
  And I purchase items
  Then I can checkout using the "<Option>"

Examples:
| User | Option |
| Arun | one    |
| Arun | two    |
| Arun | three  |
| Ajay | one    |
| Ajay | two    |
| Ajay | three  |
| Ashok| one    |
| Ashok| two    |
| Ashok| three  |
```

This will run each option for each user. I don't know how your code looks, but using the above format should be easy to adapt. Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines) as well as [how to write good Gherkin](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/)

Answer (score 0):

Your step, and the Scenario Outline seem to be doing too much.

If the users have expressly different permissions, or the method of getting to the checkout changes for each of the 3 users, then of course, 9 scenarios may be necessary for the test, if not however, you may only have to write 3 scenarios to test this.

The way I would write this test:

```
Background:
   Given I am logged in as "Arun"
     And I have gone to the checkout after selecting various products
   When I purchase the items

Scenario Outline: Checkout descriptions
   Then I should be able to checkout <with?> a description

 Examples:
   | with?   |
   | with    |
   | without |

Scenario: Checkout with description and accept the terms of service*
   Then I should be able to checkout with a description
     And I should be able to accept the terms of service*
```

* Replace "accept the terms of service" with the meaning behind your selecting of the check boxes.

Gherkin is there to bridge the conversational gap between the development team and the business, so making sure that the language used is understandable by a non-technical business person is essential. Leave implementation details out of the feature file, as it is all about describing how the system behaves.

**Edit**

If there is *real business benefit* in running the test across the 2 other users (and it isn't solely being run to set up test data, which should be done in a before hook), then perhaps you would need to do something more like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Checkout descriptions
   Given I am logged in as "<user>"
     And I have gone to the checkout after selecting various products
   When I purchase the items
   Then I should be able to checkout <with?> a description

 Examples:
   | user  | with?   |
   | Arun  | with    |
   | Ajay  | with    |
   | Ashok | with    |
   | Arun  | without |
   | Ajay  | without |
   | Ashok | without |

Scenario Outline: Checkout with description and accept the terms of service*
   Given I am logged in as "<user>"
     And I have gone to the checkout after selecting various products
   When I purchase the items
   Then I should be able to checkout with a description
     And I should be able to accept the terms of service*

 Examples:
   | user  |
   | Arun  |
   | Ajay  |
   | Ashok |
```

Comment: Thanks.And Yes I have written my scenario as mentioned above.But I thought of condensing it more to achieve another set of use cases without rewriting the scenario.I think if the background accepts Examples like Scenario Outline then my intention is Half solved.Its better I create another scenario to achieve this.

Comment: @RajeshKumar My question to you is why you would need to do that?  What business benefit would you gain by running the same test again across 2 more users? Does one user cover all of the use cases for the feature?

Comment: @RajeshKumar See my edit for the 2 more users, but definitely think about what you are trying to achieve by running these extra users, making sure that there is something now being tested that wasn't covered by using "Arun" as the sole user, because there is no benefit to running the same test 3 times, it just extends the execution time of the suite unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks.One of the main reason I tried achieving this use case is bcoz Permission for each user is different and Items available for each user also Differs based and hence I thought of having different Examples.However after the discussion with the Team I have cut down My use cases now.Now I simply need to add one more Column for Items selection along with User and Checkout and will cover the all the Items selection by mapping it with Checkout option .So that all 4 types of items selection gets covered while doing the checkout itself.Thanks for your inputs..